# Holding event in or on?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> He organized a virtual event in VirtualChat, a video game.
>
> He held a political rally in VirtualChat, a video game.
>
> The group held a protest in VirtualChat, a video game.

Not sure if it's in or on. I think it's in, but I am not 100% sure. Also, I am not sure if either one of them is correct.

Comment: Does 'a video game' really belong in lines 2 and 3? They don't make sense to me.

Comment: what would you use instead of in? you can hold a rally in a 3d game.

Comment: OK. It is *all* virtual, so you would use "in" in all three cases. Welcome to ELL btw!